# Accessing a parent class attribute as a child class attribute

Tags: python, oop

I'm using a decorator inside a class, which requires the parameters to be class-level attributes.

The below is possible, but the snippet `columns_in = BaseClass.columns_in` irks me, because it's 1) not automatic like instance-level objects and 2) requires direct re-referencing of the parent.

Is this really the proper way of "inheriting" the parent's class attributes, without making them instance attributes?

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

import pandas as pd
import daffy


class BaseClass(ABC):
    columns_in = ["A", "B", "C"]

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def decorated_method(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        ...


class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    columns_in = BaseClass.columns_in # Is this the way?

    @staticmethod
    @daffy.df_in(columns=columns_in) # Cannot reference self.columns_in
    def decorated_method(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return df


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"])

c = ChildClass()
c.decorated_method(df)
```

Comment: Why not `@daffy.df_in(columns=BaseClass.columns_in)`?

Comment: But that would accomplish the same, if not even more verbose. Especially if composing columns `BaseClass.some_columns + BaseClass.some_other_columns`. I guess there really isn't a nicer way then, given Python's constraints.